# openjdk11 compiler error: Failed to determine Xcode version

Tags: java, xcode, apple-m1, openjdk-11

I tried to compile openjdk11 in Apple M1 environment, but an error occurred in the process, resulting in the interruption of compilation.

```sh
bash configure --disable-warnings-as-errors --with-debug-level=slowdebug

checking if Boot JDK is 32 or 64 bits... 64
checking for local Boot JDK Class Data Sharing (CDS)... yes, created
checking for Build JDK... yes, will use output dir
configure: xcodebuild output: objc[97127]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x203c6ab90) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1042e82c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
configure: error: Failed to determine Xcode version.
/Users/xxx/Documents/My/Sources/java/opensource/jdk-jdk-11-28/build/.configure-support/generated-configure.sh: line 84: 5: Bad file descriptor
configure exiting with result code 1
```

I have located the location of the error in the configuration script, which seems to need to modify the script to solve the problem.

```sh
if test "x$OPENJDK_TARGET_OS" = xmacosx; then
    if test -n "$XCODEBUILD"; then
      # On Mac OS X, default toolchain to clang after Xcode 5
      XCODE_VERSION_OUTPUT=`"$XCODEBUILD" -version 2>&1 | $HEAD -n 1`
      $ECHO "$XCODE_VERSION_OUTPUT" | $GREP "Xcode " > /dev/null
      if test $? -ne 0; then
        AC_MSG_NOTICE([xcodebuild output: $XCODE_VERSION_OUTPUT])   // Output log I temporarily added
        AC_MSG_ERROR([Failed to determine Xcode version.])
      fi
      XCODE_MAJOR_VERSION=`$ECHO $XCODE_VERSION_OUTPUT | \
          $SED -e 's/^Xcode \(@<:@1-9@:>@@<:@0-9.@:>@*\)/\1/' | \
          $CUT -f 1 -d .`
      AC_MSG_NOTICE([Xcode major version: $XCODE_MAJOR_VERSION])
      if test $XCODE_MAJOR_VERSION -ge 5; then
          DEFAULT_TOOLCHAIN="clang"
      else
          DEFAULT_TOOLCHAIN="gcc"
      fi
    else
      # If Xcode is not installed, but the command line tools are
      # then we can't run xcodebuild. On these systems we should
      # default to clang
      DEFAULT_TOOLCHAIN="clang"
    fi
  else
    # First toolchain type in the list is the default
    DEFAULT_TOOLCHAIN=${VALID_TOOLCHAINS%% *}
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

i was try changed file 'toolchain.m4', $HEAD replace with $TAIL in line 231, and args '-n 1' replace with '-n 2', like that

```sh
XCODE_VERSION_OUTPUT=`"$XCODEBUILD" -version 2>&1 | $TAIL -n 2`
```

now, it is works in my mac

Comment: Plase add more details to answer better if you can add some screen shots

Comment: @TuzkiYao  I got a new mistake：configure: error: Cannot continue.
/jdk-11-28/build/.configure-support/generated-configure.sh: line 84: 5: Bad file descriptor

Comment: Does it provide more message about this error? : )